# onclick want to show the same image in 2 different div's

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get some same output as 2-way data binding of angular. here I have one image and one button. and when I click on the button the same image on top should display in another div.

```
<div id="image">
<img class="first" src="../../../morning.png">
<div id="hidden" style="height=30%; width=70%">
</div>
<button id="show">click me</button>
```

i tried with the above code to complete the html part. now i need to finish the javascript. sorry for silly question. and thank you advance for your help and time.

Comment: Are you using Angular or are you saying you want to get 2-way data binding like Angular does?

Comment: no m not using angular m using normal javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, create a dynamic image element. And append it to div. But make sure you select `image element` with particular `id`

```js
function showImage() {

  // use id selector (#) if you have one image
  let src = document.querySelector(".first").getAttribute("src")
  let x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", src);
  x.setAttribute("width", "304");
  x.setAttribute("height", "228");
  x.setAttribute("alt", "Image From first div");
  document.querySelector("#hidden").appendChild(x);

}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <img class="first" src="../../../morning.png">
  <div id="hidden" style="height=30%; width=70%">
  </div>
  <button id="show" onclick="showImage()">click me</button>
```

See this w3 school [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) to know about creating DOM image object

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

You can clone the Image element (or any other ones you want).

```
const element = document.getElementById("first");
const cloned = element.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(cloned);
```

---

### Old Answer

You can have another img tag where you want and have a condition with ngIf that will be true when clicking on the button.

```
<img class="first" src="../../../morning.png" *ngIf="shouldShowSecondImage">
```

Comment: yes thank you for your replay but actually I'm not using angular here. I'm writing this is normal javascript.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice. You can check my updated answer

Comment: thank you it to work same as first ans. but actually i dont want to clone, coz in future i'm going to write the function to hide the first image.

Comment: Sure, you can clone it and edit any attributes you want as the createElement